# Text is not going in the div tag

Tags: html, css, text, positioning

I've used float:left for some of the elements above, but i can't get the text to go in the div location...
If you look at the image you can see what i'm trying to do: put the text where the empty gray box is..

BTW it's a school project.. don't take the design too seriously.. :)

[here's what it looks like!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGHPI.png)

i'll paste my html and my css:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
<script src="js.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="cargar_pagina()">
<div class="cuerpo">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="acercaDeArriba">
    Luis Jarman <br>
    Ivan Ortega <br>
    Jose Manuel
    </div>
  <div class="barraMenu">
        <img src="images/RedNormal.png" width="112" height="30" onclick="boton_ferrari()" onMouseOver="this.src='images/RedHover.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='images/RedNormal.png';" alt=""/>      
        <img src="images/BlackNormal.png" width="112" height="30" onMouseOver="this.src='images/BlackHover.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='images/BlackNormal.png';" onclick="boton_porsche()" alt=""/>
        <img src="images/GreyNormal.png" width="112" height="30" onMouseOver="this.src='images/GreyHover.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='images/GreyNormal.png';" onclick="boton_mclaren()" alt=""/>
        <img src="images/BlueNormal.png" width="112" height="30" onMouseOver="this.src='images/BlueHover.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='images/BlueNormal.png';" onclick="boton_pagani()" alt=""/>
  </div>

            <div class="miniaturas">
                <table height="289">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img id="i1" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                        <td><img id="i2" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img id="i3" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                        <td><img id="i4" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img id="i5" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                        <td><img id="i6" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img id="i7" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                        <td><img id="i8" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             </div>
            <div class="framePhoto">
                <img id="frameFoto" src="images/porsche/porsche1.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <h4 class="titulos">PUBLICIDAD FERRARI</h4>
                <iframe class="video" width="200" height="135" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7HQ7-jnJ0J4? rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;html5=1&amp;allowfullscreen=true&amp;wmode=transparent"               frameborder="0" allowfullscreen controls></iframe>
                <h4 class="titulos">WEBS oficiales</h4>
                <ul>
                <li> <a class="enlace" href="http://www.ferrari.com/es_es/">Ferrari</a> </li>
                <li> <a class="enlace" href="http://www.porsche.com/spain/">Porsche</a> </li>
                <li> <a class="enlace" href="http://www.mclaren.com/">Mclaren</a> </li>
                <li> <a class="enlace" href="http://www.pagani.com/">Pagani</a> </li>
                </ul>
                <img class="volante" src="images/volante.png" width="200" heigt="200" alt=""/>
            </div>

              <div class="info">
                    <p class="textoDescri">Ferrari es una compañía de automóviles deportivos con sede en Maranello (Italia). Fue fundada en 1929 por un piloto de autos de competición, Enzo Ferrari, con el nombre de Scuderia Ferrari, construyendo               automóviles de competición y, más tarde, en 1947, fabricando autos deportivos.</p>
                 </div>





</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#000000;
}
.cuerpo{
    height:1200px;
    width:800px;

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-image:url(images/background4.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
.barraMenu{
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:15px;
    height:38px;
    width:490px;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-left:20px;
    background-image:url(images/barramenu.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
.acercaDeArriba{
    margin-top:177px;
    background-image:url(images/acercade.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:129px;
    width:270px;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:22px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
.framePhoto{
    background-image:url(images/frameFoto.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:364px;
    height:319px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;


}
#frameFoto:hover {
     width: 325px;
     height: 225px;
}
#frameFoto{
    alignment-adjust:central;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s, width 1s;
}
.miniaturas{
    width:130px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;

}
.container{
    display:table;
}
.containerRow{
    display:table-row;
}
.navbar{
    background-image:url(images/navbar.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:266px;
    height:550px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:5px;
}
.volante {
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
   50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
   50% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.video{
vertical-align:top;
margin-top: 0px;    
margin-left: 9px;
box-shadow: 0px 7px 2px #888888;

}

.titulos{
margin-left: 10px;
text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(238,115,115,0.93);
}

@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(Anita_semi_square.ttf);
}

.enlace{
   font-family: myFirstFont;
}
.info{
    background-image:url(images/descrip.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-top:325px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:550px;
    height:170px;

}
.textoDescri{
    padding-bottom:500px;

}
```

Comment: this is the output of your code. what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put position relative to the info div and position absolute to textoDescri like that

```
.info{
    background-image:url(images/descrip.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-top:325px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:550px;
    height:170px;
    **position:relative**

}
.textoDescri {
    **position:absolute**

}
```

[Codepin](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGNPzB)

Comment: would be great if you could give me a bit of insight as to why it works

Comment: You are welcome, position relative works as a container for position absolute, so if you put position relative for your parent div (.info) and position absolute for the child (.textoDescri) then the child will take his place in his parent.

Answer (score 0):

i move class="info" do you ok?

```css
body{
    background-color:#FFFFFFF;
}
.cuerpo{
    height:1200px;
    width:800px;

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-image:url(images/background4.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
.barraMenu{
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:15px;
    height:38px;
    width:490px;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-left:20px;
    background-image:url(images/barramenu.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
.acercaDeArriba{
    margin-top:177px;
    background-image:url(images/acercade.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:129px;
    width:270px;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:22px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
.framePhoto{
    background-image:url(images/frameFoto.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:364px;
    height:319px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;


}
#frameFoto:hover {
     width: 325px;
     height: 225px;
}
#frameFoto{
    alignment-adjust:central;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s, width 1s;
}
.miniaturas{
    width:130px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;

}
.container{
    display:table;
}
.containerRow{
    display:table-row;
}
.navbar{
    background-image:url(images/navbar.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:266px;
    height:550px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:5px;
}
.volante {
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
   50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
   50% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.video{
vertical-align:top;
margin-top: 0px;    
margin-left: 9px;
box-shadow: 0px 7px 2px #888888;

}

.titulos{
margin-left: 10px;
text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(238,115,115,0.93);
}

@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(Anita_semi_square.ttf);
}

.enlace{
   font-family: myFirstFont;
}
.info{
    background-image:url(images/descrip.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:500px;
    height:170px;
     z-index:2 ;

}
.textoDescri{
    padding-bottom:10px;
    z-index:auto;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
<script src="js.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="cargar_pagina()">
<div class="cuerpo">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="acercaDeArriba">
    Luis Jarman <br>
    Ivan Ortega <br>
    Jose Manuel
    </div>
  <div class="barraMenu">
        <img src="images/RedNormal.png" width="112" height="30" onclick="boton_ferrari()" onMouseOver="this.src='images/RedHover.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='images/RedNormal.png';" alt=""/>      
        <img src="images/BlackNormal.png" width="112" height="30" onMouseOver="this.src='images/BlackHover.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='images/BlackNormal.png';" onclick="boton_porsche()" alt=""/>
        <img src="images/GreyNormal.png" width="112" height="30" onMouseOver="this.src='images/GreyHover.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='images/GreyNormal.png';" onclick="boton_mclaren()" alt=""/>
        <img src="images/BlueNormal.png" width="112" height="30" onMouseOver="this.src='images/BlueHover.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='images/BlueNormal.png';" onclick="boton_pagani()" alt=""/>
  </div>

            <div class="miniaturas">
                <table height="289">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img id="i1" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                        <td><img id="i2" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img id="i3" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                        <td><img id="i4" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img id="i5" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                        <td><img id="i6" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img id="i7" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                        <td><img id="i8" class="mini8" src="images/mini8.png" width="60" height="58" onClick="aumentar(id)" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             </div>
            <div class="framePhoto">
                <img id="frameFoto" src="images/porsche/porsche1.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                    <p>Ferrari es una compañía de automóviles deportivos con sede en Maranello (Italia). Fue fundada en 1929 por un piloto de autos de competición, Enzo Ferrari, con el nombre de Scuderia Ferrari, construyendo               automóviles de competición y, más tarde, en 1947, fabricando autos deportivos.</p>
                 </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <h4 class="titulos">PUBLICIDAD FERRARI</h4>
                <iframe class="video" width="200" height="135" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7HQ7-jnJ0J4? rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;html5=1&amp;allowfullscreen=true&amp;wmode=transparent"               frameborder="0" allowfullscreen controls></iframe>
                <h4 class="titulos">WEBS oficiales</h4>
                <ul>
                <li> <a class="enlace" href="http://www.ferrari.com/es_es/">Ferrari</a> </li>
                <li> <a class="enlace" href="http://www.porsche.com/spain/">Porsche</a> </li>
                <li> <a class="enlace" href="http://www.mclaren.com/">Mclaren</a> </li>
                <li> <a class="enlace" href="http://www.pagani.com/">Pagani</a> </li>
                </ul>
                <img class="volante" src="images/volante.png" width="200" heigt="200" alt=""/>
            </div>

              





</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have change many things in your code, and we could talk for hours about what is a good html page. Anyway, first I suggest you to give a "schema" trying to divide your body in 2 macro div. 
One on the Left for your main content and one on the right for your sidebar.
To do that you have to follow this scheme:

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class"container">
  <div class="main-content">
   <!-- your main content here -->
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
   <!-- your sidebar content here -->
  </div> 
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.main-content {width: 66%; float: left;}
.sidebar {width: 34%; float: right;}
```

Comment: yeah! seems like a good idea, although I would probably have to re-design/re-shape most of the images :/